# After npm run build > dependency was not found VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

After

```
npm run build
```

When serving with

```
npm run serve -s dist
```

This dependency was not found:

```
/Users/zarpio/code/vuejs/p3-admin/dist in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.31.234:8081/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./dist, multi (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://192.168.31.234:8081/sockjs-node ./dist
```

To install it, you can run: npm install --save /Users/zarpio/code/vuejs/p3-admin/dist

Comment: The [`vue-cli-service serve` command](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#vue-cli-service-serve) does not accept any `-s` options. What are you trying to do here? Are you perhaps trying to [preview locally](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#previewing-locally)? If so, you're using the wrong thing. Please see the documentation I've linked

Answer (score -1):

I believe there is a dependency your project has which you have not installed. Run `npm install` to install the necessary dependencies. sometimes npm gets messed up and i need to delete the entire node modules folder and then run `npm install` to get a fresh node modules setup.

just to clear some things up.the default vue cli configuration is that `npm run serve` will run your app live locally. the `npm run build` compiles your app into the dist folder which you then can serve from your server ( or something like the live server extension in VS code)